# Friendship invite form with hobo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[The hobo lifecycle tutorial shows how to implement a friendship logic in
the model and controller.](http://cookbook.hobocentral.net/manual/lifecycles) However it does not really cover how to glue
the gui/views together. When I go to /friendships/invite - hobo
presents me with a form with a drop down menu. How do I add a form to
the user show-page with just one button (Invite) I guess that the the
user viewed should be in a hidden field?

I tried adding the form like this:

```
<extend tag="show-page" for="User">
  <old-show-page merge>
    <append-content-body:>
      <invite-form for="Friendship" />
    </append-content-body:>
  </old-show-page>
</extend>
```

Hobo ignores the invite-form hmmm I must be missing something.

Best regards
Asbjørn Morell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<invite-form:friendships.build/>`  assuming you have `has_many :friendships` on your user model.   for is an attribute on the 'def' and 'extend' tags, it's not recognized by 'form'.  To use a polymorphic tag, simply pass in an instance of the correct type in the context.   This of course is easier if an instance already exists, but since you're using a creator action, just build one.

P.S.  Questions like this get answered much quicker on the Hobo Users mailing list.